# Is it possible to apply JQuery to all anchor tags without using a class identifier?

Tags: javascript, jquery

One would usually do something like:

```
$("a.button").dblclick(function(e) { return false; });
```

where "button" is the identifying class. However in my case I have a lot of anchors to change in the site, and just want to apply this "prevent double click" feature to all anchor tags in the application

So can I alter this JQuery to apply to all anchor tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Just select all `<a>` tags.  `$("a")`.

Comment: Um... yes? `$("a").dblclick(function(e) {return false;});`...

Comment: that easy.... Wonderful.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all anchors use `$("a")`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).on("dblclick","a", function(e){return false;});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this example handles dynamically-created links, and while a good solution its added complexity may not be necessary.

Comment: Yes, I think he was looking for a catch-all, which this was intended to be.